# Accessing Python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

consider the following python snippet

```
spoon = 2 + 2

print spoon

def spoon(x):
    return x + 3

print spoon

spoon = 'foo'

print spoon
```

here we are using same name to create new objects. my doubt is how can we access the data inside the first object we created. i.e., how can i access 4 which is stored in spoon. although the name space is pointing to a new id but still the old object exists so i am asking is there anyway to access the contents of those objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Once the object becomes unreachable, it is deallocated. The interpreter may find out about this immediately if the object is subject to reference counting. In that case `4` is gone the moment you set `spoon` to `foo`.

Consider this imperfect example for demonstration

```
class Foo(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "tell my wife I love her!"


>>> f = Foo()
>>> def f():
...  print 'Make room for thy beloved king!'
...
tell my wife I love her!
>>>
```

Comment: Wasn't he asking about function/variable name definitions rather than 2 same named variables?

Comment: so here when ever a new object with same name space is created the interpreter will delete all the object associated data and starts creating a new object reference and store the new contents. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @charan: Values are like balloons, names are mere tags tied to the balloons. As soon as there are no more labels attached to a balloon, it drifts away into the sky..

Comment: @charan: If you need continued access to a balloon, make sure you have it tied down to a label somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I like this picture of the balloons.

Comment: @glglgl: I may have [used the image before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+balloons). :-)